# Show the Berry phase is invariant under $U(1)$ unitary transform

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, gauge-invariance, berry-pancharatnam-phase

Recall that $$\gamma_n = \oint A_n(R) \cdot dR = \oint \langle\psi_n(R)|i\nabla_R|\psi_n(R) \rangle \cdot dR.$$  Under the $U(1)$ transform, $$\psi_n \to \psi'_n \equiv e^{i\xi_n(R)}\psi_n,$$ where $\xi_n(R)$ is an arbitrary phase.  Show that $$\gamma_n' = \oint A'_n \cdot dR = \gamma_n.$$

Comment: I believe that self-answering a straightforward homework question is *not* a good use of that feature. In fact, it may be one of the worst uses, aside from promotion of crackpot theories.

Answer (score 0):

Under the $U(1)$ transform, $A_n \to A_n - \nabla_R \xi_n(R),$ and using Stokes theorem it immediately follows that $\gamma$ is invariant under $U(1).$